# Can't set max-width of iframe to 100%

Tags: html, css, width

I am attempting to set the width of a Bandcamp embedded player to 100%, but it is always limited to 700px – a limitation they have imposed on `div#player` via inner CSS, which I am trying to work around.

The player will stretch across the page if I change `max-width` through Developer Tools, but I don't know how to do this via CSS/HTML.

Code for embedded player:

```
<iframe style="width:100% !important; height: 274px; border: 0px" src="https://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/album=1353674788/size=large/bgcol=333333/linkcol=0f91ff/artwork=small/transparent=true/" seamless></iframe>
```

Demonstration: https://codepen.io/pen/pwRLRz

Comment: @MrLister do me a favor and try to accomplish that via codepen

Comment: @MrLister the `700px` width is inside of the iframe body content. according to https://github.com/dreamwidth/dw-free/issues/2163 the max size bandcamp supports is 700px

Comment: @hffs The width of the iframe in the codepen is as wide as the codepen's output pane (with my current window, 1225 pixels). The _content_ of the iframe, however, consists of a 700 pixel wide dark gray bar (the div with id="player") on a transparent background.

Comment: Sorry, I see what the problem is now; the `width:100% !important` on the frame threw me off.

Comment: @MrLister well great, you've just put the question I asked in different words. now how about a solution?

Comment: @hffs Sorry, but changing the contents of an iframe is impossible using CSS alone. It would be possible in JavaScript, but only if the iframe's url is on the same server as the parent window. Look up the `contentWindow` property.

Comment: @MrLister my knowledge of JS isn't advanced enough to resolve it in a way that you suggested